# C# Delegates, How to convert Texbox string to a Double. Then use the mul method to calculate and display the results

Tags: c#, delegates

[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLj7V.png)   #2 Delegate as Method Parameter
// In your Form1 class create a delegate named mathop that takes two double parameters and returns one double value. Create a method called checker that takes a delegate parameter of type mathop and two double parameters named a and b. The checker method should display the values of a and b and the result of calling the mathop delegate with arguments a and b. Demonstrate the checker by calling it twice with the two methods "add" and "mul", defined as
// double add(double a,double b) { return a+b; }
// double mul(double a,double b) { return a*b; }

using System;

```
namespace mathop{
// Creates delegate
public delegate void mathop(ref double x, ref double y);

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private double mul(ref double x, double y)
    {
        return x * y;
    }

    private double add(ref double x, double y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }

    private void multiplyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // Need to convert the two textboxes to a double and display
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Follow the directions *carefully*... *"two double parameters"* does not mean "two reference-to-double parameters". You'll get docked for simple mistakes like that. You don't need `ref` on those parameters.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! What is the specific issue you're facing, any errors?

Comment: Note that in my answe I've removed any reference to ref; you don't need it. Also pay close attention to your methods and delegate signature; your delegate returns void but your methods return values. You need to make them agree, though which way depends on what you will do overall

Answer (score 0):

The assignment is trying to teach you delegates. Delegates are a way of passing methods round like they are objects

A lot of the code we write in C# is about defining a specification so we can prove elsewhere that we are complying with the specification

This is an interface:

```
interface IPerson{
  string GetName();
}
```

To behave like an IPerson a class must have a GetName method; that's all it needs. Any class that has a GetName method is capable of meeting the specification of "is like a Person" and can be used anywhere that soecifies "something like a Person must be supplied"

We could have some classes:

```
class Student: IPerson
{
  string CourseName{ get;set; }

  string GetName() { 
    return "John the student";
  }
}

class Employee: IPerson
{
  string JobTitle{get;set;}

  string GetName() { 
    return "Jim the employee";
  }
}
```

Both of these things are different; one is a student with a course, the other is an employee with a job but they both meet the same IPerson specification and they both have a GetName. They're like oils from different manufacturers; they're different Color's and prices but they meet the same grade/spec and you can put either in your car..

```
PrintPersonName(IPerson p){

  var n = p.GetName();
  Console.WriteLine(n);

}
```

This is like your car; to work the engine just needs an oil that meets spec XYZ123. To work this method solely needs something that meets the spec of an IPerson; it doesn't matter what specific kind of class you put into it- anything that implements IPerson will do. The method only uses things available on an IPerson; just the GetName method. It doesn't try any harder, it doesn't look at whether it's a Student or Employee, it doesn't try and get course title or job title. You could make a Building class that implements IPerson, so long as a building has a name- stupid as it sounds you're fulfilling a *promise* here - "I will supply you something that has a GetName method, by virtue of implementing IPerson; you can treat it like any other IPerson regardless of what it truly is"

```
IPerson s = new Student();
IPerson e = new Employee();

PrintPersonName(s);
PrintPersonName(e);
```

So you made the spec, you made things that implemented the spec, you made something that demanded the spec. All is sorted and all promises are fulfilled

---

Delegates are like interfaces; they define a specification. Where an interface defines a specification for what an object looks like, delegates define a specification for what a *method signature* looks like.

We had IPerson that was a way of proving "the class has a GetName method"

Here you have a delegate:

```
public delegate void mathop(double x, double y);
```

..that specifies what a method must look like:

- it must take two arguments, both of which are doubles
- it must return no value

`mathop` is like `IPerson`; it doesn't force the name of the method, just like IPerson doesn't force the name of the class Student, Employee or Building. `mathop` is a way of referring to the specification

Here is a method that meets the specified rules:

```
void PrintMultiply(double a, double b){
  Console.WriteLine(a*b);
}
```

Call it what you want, call the arguments what you want, all that matters is the number of and order of and type of arguments, and the return type. This meets the spec

---

Delegates allow us to turn methods into data:

```
//make a variable called s that holds anything that looks like an IPerson 
IPerson s = new Student();

//make a variable called m that holds anything that looks like a mathop 
mathop m = PrintMultiply;
```

and with our methods-as-data we can pass them around just like we pass anything else that is "normal" data:

```
//accept anything IPerson and do something with it 
PrintThatName(IPerson p){
  Console.WriteLine(p.GetName());
}

//accept anything mathop and do something with it
RunThatMathop(mathop m){
  m(2, 4);
}
```

Remember, a `mathop` is "some method that takes two numbers and returns nothing". If we pass a mathop in as data we can run it by putting the name `m` followed by `(` and some arguments, just like any other method. This means we can swap around what specific kind of mathop we pass:

```
PrintAdd(double z, double d){
  Console.WriteLine(z+d);
}

PrintSub(double s, double p){
  Console.WriteLine(s-p);
}

PrintDivide(double g, double f){
  Console.WriteLine(g/f);
}


mathop a = PrintAdd;
mathop s = PrintSub;
mathop d = PrintDivide;


RunThatMathop(a);  //prints 6; a represents the addition of 2 and 4
RunThatMathop(s);  //prints -2; s represents the subtraction of 4 from 2
RunThatMathop(d);  //prints 0.5; a represents the division of 2 by 4
```

So, just like IPerson was "any class so long as it has a GetName", mathop is "any method so long as it takes two doubles and returns nothing".

You can write a method that takes an `IPerson` and knows exactly how to deal with it; it will have a `GetName`. You can write a method that takes a `mathop` and knows exactly how to deal with it; it will take two arguments so you can supply them

---

This is why delegates are useful; they allow parts of the program to be provided later, in ways you can't imagine, so long as the provided part meets the spec. The most obvious example is a button click handler. Microsoft write a Button that you can put on your UI but they cannot know what you will do with it/what it should do when clicked. They leave that part up to you; they just say "you must provide a method that takes arguments X, and in those arguments we will put useful info like where the button was clicked, how long it was held, how many times it was clicked, which mouse button was used.." but the crucial thing is they can't know what you will want the button to do, so they allow you to provide that, so long as you follow the spec; you know what you will get from them and they know you will provide something that meets their demands. Promises fulfilled

I trust that this info will help you do your homework but do drop a comment if anything is unclear