# Can not use Func with parameters

Tags: c#, func

I have an example for my problem.

Basically i need to pass a method to another method with parameters included.

```
public void test() {
    var test = Add(Domath(5, 5)); // should be 10
}

public int Domath (int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

public int Add (Func<int, int, int> math){
    return math();
}
```

It does not work this way and i don‘t know why. This is just a minimalistic example. Is there a way to get this working?

Comment: But, it's not right, because `DoMath(5,5)` *calls* DoMath, and then tries to send the result as the argument to Add; but Add wants a `Func`, not an `int`. If you want to specify the parameters Add shall use when it calls DoMath, it needs to take them also, or you could to wrap your DoMath in another lambda that specifies the args, and have Add take a no-arg delegate

Comment: What do you have to demonstrate for your assignment? This feels like it's upside down

Comment: Your `Add` method signature says that it takes a method which accepts two `int` parameters, and returns an `int`. So it should pass in those parameters when it calls it, e.g. `return math(5, 5)`.

Comment: Have a read of my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71916280/c-sharp-delegates-how-to-convert-texbox-string-to-a-double-then-use-the-mul-me/71922539#71922539 - i wonder if youre in the same class :D

Comment: First of all... Do you want to pass the parameters to the function that you pass to `Add`, or do you want `Add` to pass the parameters to the function you give it?  The two approaches are different, and the code shown appears to be confusing the two.

Comment: There's a definite XY problem here, what are you really trying to achieve? Why are you even trying to use a `Func` in the first place for something as simple as adding?

Answer (score 3):

Let's have a look at

```
public int Add (Func<int, int, int> math){
    return math();
}
```

You **can't** return `return math();`: note, that `math` requires **two** arguments which are not passed to `math()`. You can modify `Add` as

```
public int Domath (int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}

// We are going to add first and second
// with a help of math function
public int Add (int first, int second, Func<int, int, int> math = null) {
    // If math is not provided, we use Domath functon 
    if (math == null)
        math = Domath;

    // Finally, we call math with required two arguments
    return math(first, second);
}
```

Now you can put

```
public void test(){
    var test = Add(5, 5);
}
```

Or

```
public void test(){
    var test = Add(5, 5, Domath);
}
```

Comment: This makes no sense though. Why have an "add" method that doesn't actually add anything, and in fact might even multiply or divide or some other funky calculation?

Comment: Yeah, the OP should have inverted the names. `Domath` should have the `Func<>` delegate.